# Layout issue with Google Maps API Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, xcode8

I have an issue with Google Maps' API, using Xcode 8 with swift 3.
In the background, I should have a UIView with GMSMapView as subclass and in the foreground, there should be a marker and a view for the street number/name like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlywF.jpg).
But when I launch the app, the marker and the view disappear and I don't know why. While my app is running, we can just see my Google Maps View, as [below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUEsu.png).

So what is the problem here? Why my views are disappearing?

Answer (score 0):

This happened with me also. I did put all view on superview.